# Patch in mail thread format--How?

Tags: git, format-patch, email-threading, git-am

I am developing a tool with 3 others. We usually communicate via patches in git. This is how we do:
1. A makes changes, creates patch using format-patch, attaches it to mail(outlook) and send.
2. B and C download, place at `x` location and apply using am.

My questions are:

1. Are we doing anything wrong? (coz we have to explicitly attach patch to outlook and download)
2. Is there a tool or a way that I can see the patches to and fro in [this](http://www.gelato.unsw.edu.au/archives/git/0602/17154.html) format? So that I have the whole patch Conversation at once from git itself so that I don't need to look into outlook for conv history.